# Split a tuple with string array into multiple tuples

Tags: apache-pig

I have this set of tuples like

```
A = 
(1, ["Football","Baseball"])
(2, ["Swimming","Baseball"])
```

I want to split the tuples based upon the string array so that the end result is something like this

```
(1, "Football")
(1, "Baseball")
(2, "Swimming")
(2, "Baseball")
```

How can I do this in pig?

Answer (score 0):

First remove the `'['` and `']'` character from the input using `REPLACE` function and then wrap the output into `bag` and `flatten` it.

**input**

```
1,["Football","Baseball"]
2,["Swimming","Baseball"]
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:int,f2:chararray,f3:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1,FLATTEN(TOBAG(REPLACE(f2,'[\\[\\]]',''),REPLACE(f3,'[\\[\\]]','')));
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(1,"Football")
(1,"Baseball")
(2,"Swimming")
(2,"Baseball")
```

Comment: @Sivasajthi. Actually, there aren't 3 columns there are 2 columns, the first one is the id and the second one is an array of games the person with the  given id likes. It is not a string but a array of strings.

Comment: @user12331, Pig doesn't support array kind of datatype, the above input will be treated as simple string not array of strings( pig doesn't have any intelligence to know its a array of string). when you apply ',' as a delimiter then pig will segregate your input as (col1=1, col2=["Football" and col3="Baseball"] ).